# Klipfolio SSO Implementation in ASP.NET

Tags: single-sign-on

need some help.

i've been trying to implement Klipfolio dashboard and it seems i cannot get it to work in the office.  i really don't know why.  when using IE its not working but using Chrome or Firefox it working fine.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // initialize
            function initKlipfolioSSO(onSuccess, onError) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "https://app.klipfolio.com/users/sso_auth",
                    xhrFields: {
                        withCredentials: true
                    },
                    crossDomain: true,
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    headers: {
                        "KF-SSO": "07U0rGlLbLevocLRIzHoChJdDTT7C7VlufgvU1ExrcrrBS7dwidFWaTr5l8ONrzUOw+Dq8wHFPVFjE5ycx5t4Uddi+RcDvS8WANWwH9IDKI=",
                        "KF-Company": "4b1a81c1d9005e1ac78f33aaac465e6f"
                    },
                    dataType: "json", 
                    success: function (data) {
                        onSuccess(data);
                    },

                    error: function (err) {
                        onError(data);
                    }

                })
            };


            $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
                initKlipfolioSSO(
                    function (data) { document.location = "https://app.klipfolio.com/dashboard" },
                    function (data) { alert("Dashboard is temporarily unavailable."); }
                );
            })
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input style='margin-top: 10px' type='button' id='btnSubmit' value='Submit SSO Token' /></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does it "not work"? Are there any error messages?

Comment: using chrome or firefox it was successful.  but using IE.. error is "Transport Error"